# Flutter - Open bottom sheet from bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bottomnavigationview, bottom-sheet

Following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9EnOCpuCrw&ab_channel=TeamArtisans) tutorial I have implemented GetX Bottom Navigation Bar. Now on click of a specific item I want to open a Bottom Sheet. Bottom Sheet will contain linked label of more screens.

Here is the code for HomeController.dart

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class HomeController extends GetxController {
  var tabIndex = 0;

  void changeTabIndex(int index) {
    tabIndex = index;
    update();
  }
}
```

Here is the code for HomeScreen.dart

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<HomeController>(
      builder: (controller) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: IndexedStack(
            index: controller.tabIndex,
            children: [
              Screen1(),
              Screen2(),
              Screen3(),
              Screen4(),
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
            showSelectedLabels: true,
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.green,
            showUnselectedLabels: true,
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 0,
            onTap: controller.changeTabIndex,
            currentIndex: controller.tabIndex,
            items: [
              _bottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home_filled),
                label: "Screen 1",
              ),
              _bottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                label: "Screen 2",
              ),
              _bottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.sim_card_rounded),
                label: "Screen 3",
              ),
              _bottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.phone_in_talk_rounded),
                label: "Screen 4",
              ),
              _bottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                label: "",
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  _bottomNavigationBarItem({dynamic icon, String? label}) {
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: icon,
      label: label,
    );
  }
}
```

I want output something like this:

[image]

If it can be achieved with any other widget it would also help. TIA

Answer (score 0):

wrap your widget inside a stack like this

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    
   GetBuilder<HomeController>(
    childern
   ), 

  if(showMenu)? YourMenuWidget(
     Inkwell(child: Container(), onTap(){
        // hide menu
        showMenu = false ;
        setState();
     }),
     childern etc
    ) : Container(),
    
  ],
)
```

and in click listener of '...' menu set showMenu to true (a variable in state) and set State

this code is not compliable but a general idea how you can approach this.